# What does the error `Could not deduce (a ~ b)` mean?

Tags: haskell, types

I am modifying the following code as part of an assignment:

```
rand :: Random a => State StdGen a
rand = do
    gen <- get
    let (x, gen') = random gen
    put gen'
    return x
```

I was asked to write a function `randR` that accomplishes the same task as the `rand` function but allows for a range to be specified. The desired type is `Random a => (a, a) -> State StdGen a`. I wrote the following code:

```
randR :: Random a => (a, a) -> State StdGen b
randR (lo, hi) = do
    gen <- get
    let (x, gen') = randomR (lo, hi) gen
    put gen'
    return x
```

This looks correct; it's almost exactly like the model. But I get the following error:

```
Could not deduce (a ~ b)
from the context (Random a)
  bound by the type signature for 
             randR :: Random a => (a, a) -> State StdGen b
```

What does `(a ~ b)` mean, and why can't the compiler "deduce" it from the "context"?

Comment: What are all of your imports? I'm trying to get your code working.

Comment: Or - what is the definition of your `State` type? Is it from a a module like `Control.Monad.State` or did your instructor define it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message indicates that there's a typo in the signature for `randR`: `randR :: Random a => (a, a) -> State StdGen b`. It should be `... -> RandState a`.

The message roughly states that the compiler knows that `a` and `b` need to be the same type but that it can't prove that to be the case. `a ~ b` is an ["equality constraint"](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/equality-constraints.html); read `~` as roughly meaning `=`.

The part about the context is simply the compiler's way of telling you what it *does* know about the type constraints. In this case, it's almost completely unhelpful, but frequently you'll see something like `Could not deduce (Floating a) from the context (Num a)` or some other straightforward indication that the function needs an additional constraint.

Incidentally, with some extensions you *could* fix this problem by adding the constraint GHC asks for: `randR :: (Random a, a ~ b) => (a, a) -> State StdGen b` should work fine. (I think.) For your purposes, don't worry about this...