# Why does GHC produce an equality constraint error rather than a type match error here?

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, ghc

Following up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26919382/1186208), I'm not sure why these two code snippets produce completely different errors:

```
f :: a -> b
f x = x
-- Couldn't match expected type `b' with actual type `a'
-- In the expression: x

g :: Monad m => a -> m b
g x = return x
-- Could not deduce (a ~ b) from the context (Monad m)
-- In the first argument of `return', namely `x'.
```

What is the rule giving rise to this behavior?

It's not very readable, even to someone familiar with standard Haskell; the equality constraint `(a ~ b)` requires a language extension.

Note that, as chi pointed out, the mere presence of a constraint triggers the constraint error:

```
class C a

h :: C a => a -> b
h x = x
-- Could not deduce...
```

(An empty constraint, `() => a -> b`, gives the match not the constraint error.)

Comment: Add any context to `f` and you will trigger the equality constraint error: e.g. `f :: Show a => a -> b`

Comment: While not strictly wrong, the message "Could not deduce (a ~ b)" is probably not very good in this case for a beginner who isn't aware what the `~` symbol means. So as for "why" - I would say it's a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's a shorter answer than digging into GHC internals to understand why.

If you run GHC with the `-ddump-tc-trace` switch, you can get quite a lengthy log of the typechecking process. In particular, if you run it on this code:

```
f :: a -> b
f x = x

class C a

h :: C c => c -> d
h x = x
```

you can see that typechecking `a` vs `b`, and typechecking `c` vs `d` progresses exactly the same way in both cases, culminating in the following two unsolved constraints (output is from GHC 7.8.2):

```
tryReporters { [[W] cobox_aJH :: c ~ d (CNonCanonical)]
...
tryReporters { [[W] cobox_aJK :: a ~ b (CNonCanonical)]
```

By following the rabbit hole a bit more in `TcErrors`, you can see that for equalities on skolems, `tryReporters` eventually gets to creating the error message via `misMatchOrCND`, which has an explicit special case for empty contexts:

```
misMatchOrCND :: ReportErrCtxt -> Ct -> Maybe SwapFlag -> TcType -> TcType -> SDoc
-- If oriented then ty1 is actual, ty2 is expected
misMatchOrCND ctxt ct oriented ty1 ty2
  | null givens ||
    (isRigid ty1 && isRigid ty2) ||
    isGivenCt ct
       -- If the equality is unconditionally insoluble
       -- or there is no context, don't report the context
  = misMatchMsg oriented ty1 ty2
  | otherwise
  = couldNotDeduce givens ([mkTcEqPred ty1 ty2], orig)
```

Comment: Naively reading `misMatchOrCND`, shouldn't `isRigid ty1 && isRigid ty2` be `True`? Aren't all the types in play here rigid?

Comment: See the definition of `isRigid` in the same module; I don't see how it could return True for any type variables at all. Note that it's not the same as `isRigidOrSkol`.